# float:left transform:rotate free space between divs

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

Is it possible to draw a gray box to the rotated text? I can do it by relative shift, but then shifted divs will move on a new line.

```css
#specSZ {
  position:relative;
  top:75px;
  left:-70px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  float:left;
  width:190px;
}
.specBox {
  left:-100px;
  width:190px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:silver;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<div id="specSZ">ТЕКСТ</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
<div class="specBox">
  <span>ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thenk solve the problem turnover rotate text to one more div.